# angular loaded web components not detecting property changes

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-component

I have defined one custom element for todo item with [custom element js](http://dinesh.glitch.me/custom-todo.js) and I'm using this custom element in angular file and able to pass property. Problem i am facing wherever i am adding/deleting new item it's not reflecting in custom elements

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-web-comp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Apparently angular has problems with change detection on these custom elements. I'd recommend converting it into a angular component so input change detection works properly. I made a hacky solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-element-cdr?file=src/app/app.component.ts) but that's obviously not the solution.

Comment: Instead make a child component

Answer (score 0):

**Update** really it's not a good answer, It's look like the problem is when you import the script using

```
<script src="https://dinesh.glitch.me/custom-todo.js?113"></script>
```

Futhermore, at least it's necessary add `this.render()` in the method `deleteItem`:

```
deleteItem(idx) {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent("delete", { detail: { idx, scope: this } })
    );
    this.render(); //<--add this line
  }
```

You can put the script in the index to work, see the [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-web-comp-rt6yq5?file=src%2Findex.html) but I can not to make work using `<script src="..."></script>`

Anyway, make a toDo in Angular it's easy, as Mike suggest make it in Angular.

Comment: Thanks @eliseo, it works, We are trying to create web components and sharing across different framework or lib, Todo is just to test some basic options. Also component is not behave correctly even we include in angular.json